# Pagina hecha en bootstrap para servidor Debian 9

Tags: html, sql, css, bootstrap

Estoy empezando con la creación de pagina web con el framework
bootstrap y Termine una pagina básica que tiene un login (pretendo conectarlo a sql  por php) la duda que tengo es que en el servidor debian tengo apache2 en donde quiero guardar la pagina que sera mostrada (var/www/html/index.html) esos archivo de bootstrap (los paso por FTP) debo ponerlos también junto con el index?
la maquina donde trabajo el bootstrap tiene windows. gracias

Comment: Así es debes colocarlos junto con index, si es que te refieres a los archivos de javascript o css de bootstrap.

Comment: Si con las carpetas de jss y css  voy a probarlo ahora, Gracias por contestar esta duda